How to configure description in alerts for Prometheus
The problem is: I don't recive descriprion of my alert to telegram
I have a strange issue. There are several rules
first one works greate
cat trafic_rules.yml
groups:
- name: Trafic value
  rules:
  - alert: Trafic recived by host
    expr: rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{device!="lo"}[30s])/1024/1024 > 100
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: high
    annotations:
      summary: "Trafic value for {{ $labels.instance}} ip: {{ $labels.ip }}) is greater then 100 Mib
      description: "Trafic issue for ip {{ $labels.ip }}"

and the second one:
cat availability.yml
groups:
- name: Instance DOWN
  rules:
  - alert: Host is DOWN
    expr: up == 0
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: high
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance not available {{$labels.ip}}"
      description: "ip {{$labels.ip}} problem"

and I don't recive summary or description to telegram cos of {{$labels.ip}}
here is my template for telegram
 cat telega.tmpl
Status:  {{ .Status }}
Alertname: {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }}

Description: {{.CommonAnnotations.description}}
Summary:     {{.CommonAnnotations.summary}}

Instance: {{ .CommonLabels.instance }}


if I remove {{$labels.ip}} from a description I will recive a text, bot I need this value.
How can I solve this problem?

Does your up metric include ip labels? I suspect that your up metrics does not include ip labels and therefore the second rule's summary and description don't include this value either.

I don't know whether your alert is for public or private use but it contains a couple of spelling mistakes. Trafic is correctly spelled Traffic and recived is received.

don't worry about spelling mistakes, original summary/description language is not english. I translate summary/description just for easement


Does your up metric include ip labels?

what does it mean?

@Konstantin You need to check whether promql up{} response has an ip label, if not and you want to have this label, you can change the scrape configuration of prometheus to add it.

everything is ok with a label. if a enable option "show annotations" in a prometheus's dashboard it shown correctly.
it seems that my question is not abount labels.
addtion information: If there is only one alert - everything is fine and I receive a correct description, but if the alert triggers simultaneously for several nodes, there is no additional information. Perhaps it is necessary to configure alertmanager
